# Need a div to slide down from top of my website on the right side

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I want to activate a div to slide down from the top of my page, it will be activated by a button near the menu.... I currently have a dive that slides from the right and left, but need one that appears from the top and slides down... and ideas where I could find this code?

Comment: Find the code? Why don't you make it? Or.. what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide more detail on similar code you wish to mimic or have tried already.

Comment: This is the code I allready have on my site, but it only goes left or right, I want the same thing but to appear from the top http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/

Answer (score 0):

**JS:** http://jsfiddle.net/kychan/8GBdY/

```
$('.click').click(function()
{
    $('.hidden').slideDown();
});
```

This is JQuery btw.

### As a switch: http://jsfiddle.net/kychan/8GBdY/1/

```
// initially hide the div.
$('.hidden').hide();

// listen to click event.
$('.click').click(function()
{
    // if it is visible.
    if ($('.hidden').is(':visible'))
        // hide it.
        $('.hidden').slideUp();
    else
        // show it.
        $('.hidden').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: interesting now what about clicking so it hides the content again?

Comment: very nice, well one more question, what If I wanted to have it slide from the top of the page, as if it is appearing from the top, I guess it has to do with positioning?

Comment: Hahaha, indeed. We just move the div 'hidden' to the top... It's that simple: http://jsfiddle.net/kychan/8GBdY/2/

Comment: Your welcome for the effort? At least accept my answer.

Comment: Sorry Kai for not replying but I need something a bit more, I didn't want to bug you with more question, I do appreciate the help though!